# Works perfectly in jsfiddle, but not in live website. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

Website test page: http://www.lantiis.com/indexold.html

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Guhb4/7/

I received help with the jQuery and it works perfect in jsFiddle. (temp sign-in as Lantiis here: [Can independently show/hide. How do I hide on show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182281/can-independently-show-hide-how-do-i-hide-on-show))

When I transfered the code, everything worked except the images. The background images show up, the link images show up, but not the main images that have the site content which is what I needed the jquery for. I have no idea what I did wrong when I transferred the code over.

I am sure this is just a stupid mistake on my part, but as I am still learning js, I am at a total loss at this point. I thought I had it pretty good until I posted my first question and saw how messy my code was in comparison to the users code who helped me.

Any and all direction and criticism is welcome.

Comment: On JSFiddle you have the Javascript starting OnLoad. Maybe you forgot to associate this "show-images" code to this handler in your live site?

Comment: Also, if your previous question has been solved (the one you link to), you should select an answer by clicking on the checkbox next to the answer which helped you.

Comment: I wish I could note which one I used (they all helped just like with these posts), but because I used a temp log on, there are no checkmarks available. :( And I don't have enough rep to vote up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery library in your HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

And wrap your jQuery code in the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Your code here
    });
</script>
```

http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew I was forgetting something simple. And thank you for the resource links! They are incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to including the jQuery library (as mentioned by Callum) and placing your code within an onload function (as mentioned by CleverQuack), your script also needs to have a type of text/javascript, not just javascript.  Something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $('#mask > div:first-child').show();
 $('#top a').click(function() {
    var keyterm = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#mask > div').hide();
    $('div[id=' + keyterm + ']').slideDown('slow');
 });
});
</script>
```